# BigQuery Analytics current day query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to write a query that could be executed every day to get up to date statistics for my analytic events.
Unfortunately my table path looks like this:

> appname-72a9c.analytics_211719331.events_20210418

I can easily query data by providing hardcoded string, but is there a way to dinamically specify the date?

I tried writing something like this:

```
SELECT
  e.param1, e.param2
FROM
  FORMAT_DATETIME("appname-72a9c.analytics_211719331.events_%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()) AS e
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the date string piece of your table name like this:

```sql
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.events_*`
WHERE parse_date('%Y%m%d', _table_suffix) = CURRENT_DATE() -1
```

This is a way to hardcode a query for yesterday, which you could customise as required.